Can I be accepted into another university for masters in a different subfield of the same subject?
Im finishing my masters in aerospace engineering on the subfield of propulsion. During my studies I got really hooked on spacecraft design and their applications. Is it possible to get another masters but this time in spacecraft design in another university in another country?

In brief, yes, depending on the country. But, equally, depending on your goals it's not necessarily a good idea. Related: Can a masters student apply for a second masters in the same field at another university?
